# Laravel - Sorted collection output is not an array

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to sort a collection by the column `name`. I am logging the ajax result and when I sort by `name` I get:

`Object: {0: Object, 1: Object, ...}`

But when I sort by the other field (`locationId`) I get:

`[Object, Object, ...]`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I need the result in an array like when I sort by `locationId`.

```
public function getLocations()
{
    return \Location::all(['locationId', 'name'])->sortBy('name');
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. Could you post any other relevant code.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you sort by `locationId`, the keys for the items don't change, since the items were sorted that way already. For example, the keys would stay 0, 1, 2, etc., which is a valid indexed array.

However, when you sort by the `name` field, the keys will move around with the item they reference. So, your keys may end up like 0, 2, 1, etc. Since this order of keys is not a valid indexed array, it is treated as an associative array, which is translated into an object in json.

You just need to rekey the items array after the sort. The Collection has a `values()` method to do this.

```
public function getLocations()
{
    return \Location::all(['locationId', 'name'])->sortBy('name')->values();
}
```

Comment: 4 years later I can't believe this is not called automatically when you're returning a Collection as a response, and it's so hard to find the right keywords for this answer!

Comment: Still valid answer in `Laravel 8` when you use `sortBy('')` items remains with their original keys while their reallocated already and this may cause chaos on displaying so to get rid of keys `sortBy('attribute')->values()` will return only sorted items.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of numerical keys you should use:

```
return \Location::all(['locationId', 'name'])->sortBy('name')->values()->all();
```

[Reference - sortBy](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortby)

Comment: Adding the `all()` method will return an array of the underlying items, not the Collection object. The original function returned the Collection, so I would assume this return type should not be changed.